# Vertical alignment for subtables

Tags: tables

I want to do vertical alignment of subtables. The following is a minimal example of the tables I have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Test1}
    \begin{subtable}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtable 1}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Col 1} & Col 2 \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Cell 1} & 1 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{.3\linewidth}
        \caption{Subtable 2}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Col 1} & Col 2 \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Cell 1} & 1 \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Cell 2} & 2 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}% 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This generates the following type of table

[image: Not Aligned tables]

What to do if I want to get a table like this (edited in paint):

[image: Aligned tables]

Comment: Can I use `subfloat` instead of `subtable`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the optional argument of the `subtable` environment:

```
\begin{subtable}[t]{.3\linewidth}
```

Answer (score 4):

To complement @Bernard answer I had to also set *[t]* in the **tabular** element.

```
\begin{subtable}[t]{.48\linewidth}
```

and

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{lrl}
```